# What is the Input Range for the FFT function in the NE10 library

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft, neon

I am using the [NE10 library](https://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/doc/index.html) to perform a single-dimensional FFT on some audio data for a project. However, the results I'm getting from my audio input are pretty bizarre.

I am using the float32 version of the FFT, and I noticed in the [sample code](https://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/doc/NE10_sample_real_fft_8c-example.html) that the input values are multiplied by 50. This is pretty bizarre to me. In my experience, when working in float audio data is bounded to (-1, 1).

Digging further into the documentation, I noticed that the input data for the [test code](http://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/doc/test__suite__fft__float32_8c_source.html) is scaled to match a 16-bit integer, which confused me even further.

A snippet of my code, for reference :

```
mFftConfig = ne10_fft_alloc_r2c_float32(size);
mFftDestination = new ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t[mSize/2 + 1];
mWindow = MakeWindow();

...

for(int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
{
  mInputBuffer[i] *= mWindow[i];
}
ne10_fft_r2c_1d_float32(mFftDestination, mInputBuffer, mFftConfig);
```

Long story short, I'm handing the FFT function float data between (-1, 1) and getting weird results, and I can't find any information on the FFT's input range.

Comment: What do you mean by *weird results*? Scaling issue only? A typical test of FFT programmes is to perform FFT + IFFT and to compare the result with the original data. Did you do something similar?

Comment: @Damien the FFT -> IFFT gives a result that is relatively close to the original. The weird results are in the frequency domain result, which features an enormous 0th bin value regardless of input, and very small bin values elsewhere

Comment: Could you provide some example data? For example, if all data are positive, it is normal to get a very large 0th bin value

Comment: Well, it turns out that I probably should've plugged my headphones in. I thought I was feeding a complex waveform into the FFT...it was a sinusoid. I'm still puzzled by the sample code, but it seems like the results of the FFT did make sense. Thanks for your help in getting me to that realization

Comment: You welcome. Happy to have helped, even if just a little bit